# How to "un-sparse" a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which its dtypes is :

```
Sparse [int, 0]
```

How can I "un-sparse" it? i.e. converting it to dtype of regular int?

I have tried `.astype(int)` but it does not cancel the sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `df.sparse.to_dense()`

[Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html)